# Is possible to perform an early goal test with A* using a consistent heuristic?

Tags: heuristics, a-star, consistent-heuristic

I have a doubt about A* goal test.

As far as I know an **early goal test** is performed when a node (representing a certain state) is inserted in the **frontier** or, to conform with AIMA terminology, when is **reached/generated**.

Quoting AIMA 4ed:

> (...) with a consistent heuristic, the first time we **reach** a state it will be on an **optimal path**, so we never have to re-add a state to the frontier, and never have to change an entry in reached.

With this piece of information I suppose that an **early goal test** is totally **safe**, but I wasn't able to find anything about it on the internet to confirm my hypothesis, so my second guess is that I am wrong about it.

Am I wrong? Did I misunderstood something?

Comment: Yes, you can. It's an extremely common optimization to early-exit like this in pathfinding code when you know for sure the heuristic will always be consistent.

Comment: Is early goal test ok even with multiple goal states? I think it is not. It is true that we can adapt a problem with multiple goal states to a problem with one goal state by connecting all goal states to an unique goal state, but this is equivalent to perform a late goal test with the original goal states in my opinion.